# Keeping track of the number of Children of a GameObject

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, children

I wrote this bit of code to count the children of a GameObject in my scene. It works but doesn't feel like the most elegant solution (particularly the line where I reset the childCount to 0 each time). Could someone offer me some re-write suggestions on this to make it more streamlined?

```
public int childCount;

public void countChildren() 
{
    GameObject buildBoard = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Board");

    GameObject[] allChildren = buildBoard.transform.Cast<Transform>().Select(t=>t.gameObject).ToArray();

    childCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < allChildren.Length; i++)
    {
        childCount++;
    }

    Debug.Log(childCount);
}
```

Comment: `allChildren.Length` is the number of children in your `GameObject`

Comment: You can simply use `transform.ChildCount` for `gameObject` of your desired `tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have to cast to `Transform` because [`GameObject.transform`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-transform.html) already returns `Transform` type. And `Transform` already has [`Transform.childCount`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-childCount.html) method. So you can count like this:

```
public int childCount;
public void countChildren() 
{
    GameObject buildBoard = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Board");

    childCount = buildBoard.transform.childCount;

    Debug.Log(childCount);
}
```

You can also wrap it into a little helper method:

```
public int CountChildrenForObjectWithTag(string tag)
{
    var gameObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(tag);

    if (gameObject == null || gameObject.transform == null) return 0;

    return gameObject.transform.childCount;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a static variable inside your GameObject class. Each time you add or remove anything, you can simply update it internally within your class. This static variable will be consistent across each GameObject and will be reflected if a change is made in any of them. By providing a read-only property you can access this count from any object.

```
public class GameObject
{
    private static int childrenCount = 0;
    public int ChildrenCount { get { return childrenCount; } }

    // the rest of your logic
}
```

Comment: Probably a better use of memory as well, as you're not having to recount every cycle. Although, a multiplayer game would require the other method, perhaps, as each client would potentially store different values. The game server should keep a running count to send via sockets to each client.

Comment: Not sure that he can modify the default unity `GameObject` class. Can extend it though. But then he will have to cast a lot because all framework methods return `GameObject`.